# Nativescript - binded property in view is not updated when the model is set in promise.then()

Tags: javascript, binding, promise, nativescript

I have a simple Nativescript app.

When I update *model.path* property it is set correctly and Label in UI is showing its value.

But when I set the *model.path* property in the *.then(...)* function of returned promise (*new Promise(...)*) the property is set (alert in *uploadFile(...)* method is showing a right value), but Label in UI is not updated anymore. Why?

main-page.xml:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">
    <StackLayout>
        <Button width="200" height="66" text="Record!" tap="recordVideo"></Button>
        <Label text="{{path}}"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

main-page-model.ts:

```
import { Observable }  from 'data/observable';

export class MainPageModel extends Observable {
    private _path: string;

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    public get path(): string {
        return this._path;
    }

    public set path(value: string) {
        this._path = value;
        super.notify({ object: this, eventName: Observable.propertyChangeEvent, propertyName: "path", value: this._path });
    }
}
```

main-page.ts:

```
import { VideoRecorder }  from 'nativescript-videorecorder';
import { MainPageModel }  from './main-page-model';
import { EventData } from "data/observable";
import { Page } from "ui/page";

var model: MainPageModel;

export function pageLoaded(args: EventData) {
    let page = <Page>args.object;
    model = new MainPageModel();
    page.bindingContext = model;
}

export function recordVideo() {
    model.set("path", "clieckedd");
    let videorecorder = new VideoRecorder();
    let options = {
        saveToGallery: true, //default false | optional
        duration: 10, //(seconds) default no limit | optional
        size: 10, //(MB) default none | optional #android
        hd: false, //default  false low res | optional
        explanation: "Why do i need this permission" //optional on api 23 #android
    };

    videorecorder.record(options)
    .then((data) => {
        model.set("path", data.file);
        uploadFile(model);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        model.path = err;
    });
}

function uploadFile(model: MainPageModel) {
    alert(model.path);
}

exports.model = model;
```

Thank you

Comment: I have the same problem in another use case: `status = new BehaviorSubject<string>(""); channel.subscribe( m => this.onMessage)`. onMessage updates the status with `status.next("bla")` the property is updated correctly but, no ui state change ultil I click some button, which trigger the update. I'm using angular, I not sure what is happening, the documentation says nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is because you used the `set` method of Observable , which is `model.set("path", data.file);`
, instead of your `public set path(value: string)`. That's why the `super.notify` is not called thus the label UI does not get updated to the new value. I think it should be `model.path(data.file)`

Comment: `model.path(data.file)` cannot be used, it is a property, not a method.
But to your answer, I was using `model.path = data.file;` first, but it was working neither. And than someone wrote me I should use `model.set('path', data.file);` instead, which also didn't help.

Comment: well, make it a method then, like: `public setPath(value:string) {}`. And put the notify inside of course